Distribution of execution between phases of I/O callbacks in node.js
The node.js event loop is still so poorly described in the documentation that we have to ask more questions..
There are two phases: pending callbacks and poll, both, as the documentation says, executes I/O callbacks. But the difference is that the pending callbacks phase will executes deferred I/O callbacks.
How do I know when deferred I/O callbacks are executed?
Answer that I expect:
Practical code examples that could clearly indicate in which phase I/O callbacks will be executed.
P.S Another one question to which there will most likely not be an answer.

Can you clarify what answer do you expect? You likely refer to this doc https://nodejs.org/en/learn/asynchronous-work/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick , but it already contains the explanation, "This phase executes callbacks for some system operations such as types of TCP errors. For example if a TCP socket receives ECONNREFUSED when attempting to connect, some nix systems want to wait to report the error. This will be queued to execute in the pending callbacks phase."

The problem with the node.js documentation is that it does not provide practical examples; from this it is impossible to understand these cases. All understanding is reduced to nothing.

@EstusFlask Classic survivorship bias. I thought so if I don’t write about it (ECONNREFUSED), then they will write it to me as an answer or comment. Yes, there is the only example with a TCP error. So they want to say that this stage is only for TCP errors? I doubt.

From the context it looks like it serves for platform-dependent edge cases, I'd like to see real-world examples as well

@EstusFlask I've read quite a lot of answers on SO and even looked at the node.js source code. I'm sure that the pending callbacks phase is used for all I/O callbacks, since in the old node.js documentation the poll phase never said that it calls I/O callbacks. Well, some people also strictly said that all I/O callbacks are called in pending callbacks (previously called I/O callbacks phase in old version of node.js doc).

But it seems no one will answer (there will be no examples)... it needs to write to the developers of node.js or libuv to find out.
